# Microsoft Intune App SDK on Android API 18

Tags: android, azure, intune

The documentation for the sdk states *"The SDK supports Android API 19 (Android 4.4+) through Android API 28 (Android 9.0)."*

The app I will be working on has *minSdkVersion 18*. Do I need to increase my minSDKVersion or will the Intune SDK simply not work on Android API 18 and lower?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the library with

```
<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="microsoft intune package name" />
```

This will override the min sdk of that library. But it may break the library and can lead to erros and bugs.

The best way would be to increase your minSdk to 19 which is probably no problem since you would only loose 0.5% audience: https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards

Comment: Thanks, just confirmed with team that I am able to increase Android 23 (...its legacy code)